# GridView RowCommand Not Firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I'm having trouble figuring out why the RowCommand isn't firing. Oddly enough, I have a different GridView on the page and its RowCommand is firing without issue so I have no idea what the problem could be.

I have the following code:

**JavaScript**

```
function displayPayees() {
        $('#payeeList').css("display", "block");
        $('#payeeList').dialog({
            modal: true,
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
            maxHeight: 600,
            width: 800,
            position: { my: "center top", at: "center top+15%", of: window }
        }); 
    }
```

**.aspx Page**

```
<div id="payeeList" title="Available Payees" style="display:none;">
    <asp:GridView ID="gvPayees" runat="server" Visible="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" Width="100%" AllowSorting="True" OnRowCommand="gvPayees_RowCommand" CssClass="table table-striped">
        <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" Height="15px" BackColor="#46596b" Wrap="False"></HeaderStyle>
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="TaxID" HeaderText="Tax ID"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Address1" HeaderText="Address"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Address2" HeaderText="Address 2"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="State" HeaderText="State"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Zip" HeaderText="Zip"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSelectPayee" runat="server" Text="Select" CssClass="btn btn-default home-btn btn-sm" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="SelectPayee" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("TaxID") & "~" & Eval("Name") & "~" & Eval("Address1") & "~" & Eval("Address2") & "~" & Eval("City") & "~" & Eval("State") & "~" & Eval("Zip") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

**Code Behind**

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            BindDetails()
        End If
End Sub

Protected Sub gvPayees_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)
    Throw New Exception("Hello?") 'Test code
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

I noticed that moving the GridView out of it's containing `div` causes the RowCommand to fire properly.

I'm using [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) to put the GridView into a dialog box to be displayed on a button click. I have `display: none` on the containing `div` so that the GridView is invisible until the button click and I think that may be the source of my problem. I'm updating my code here to reflect that.

**How can I hide the `div` until button click without preventing the RowCommand from firing properly?**

Comment: do you have `EnableEventValidation="true"` in your page ?

Comment: @AfnanAhmad - I don't have `EnableEventValidation` explicitly set at all in my code. I've already tried setting it to both `true` and `false` though with no change in the result.

Comment: What makes it so strange to me is that I have another GridView on that page that works fine. As best as I can tell, all the code is identical except for names (of course) and the fact that the other GridView uses an `<asp:ImageButton>` instead of a regular button.

Comment: I've ran into this on occasion. Once I've exhausted everything, I deleted the grid and remade it. That fixed it. Don't know why though.

Comment: Also, just for kicks, set `CommandArgument="test"`. It shouldn't matter if one of your items is null, but you never know.

Comment: I updated the OP with newly discovered info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change it from a `Button` to a `LinkButton` and it will work.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSelectPayee" runat="server" CommandName="SelectPayee" 
        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("TaxID") %>' >Select</asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Apparently the jQuery UI dialog places the modal outside the `</form>` tag, so normal buttons don't work anymore. But LinkButtons use JavaScript to perform the PostBack, and they are still registered within the framework.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

first of all you should assign the command name to the buttom in item template like this :

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="Btn1" CssClass="SelectRow" CommandName="Sign" runat="server"
        CausesValidation="false"
        CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex %>" 
        Text="" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

in the code behind

```
protected void gvPayees_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Sign")
    {
        GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);

        int RowIndex = gvr.RowIndex;
        gvPayees.SelectedIndex = RowIndex;    
    }
}
```

Comment: This didn't solve my problem. The RowCommand still isn't firing.

Comment: I also updated the question. I discovered that removing the GridView from its parent `div` gets the RowCommand to fire properly. I'm guessing my problem stems from the fact that I'm hiding the GridView until a button is clicked. I'm just not sure how to fix it.