# ViewState lost for controls which appear after/below a control with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I hope I can explain this properly.

I have a page in ASP.net (3.5) containing a GridView. I have implemented jquery to freeze columns and headers of the GridView (the jquery I implemented can be found here: http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/).

Now, the frustrating part. Any control I place on the page, above the GridView maintains view state on post back. Any control following the GridView loses view state on post back.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbx_Value1" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="tbx_Value2" runat="server" />
<asp:GridView ID="gv_Data" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="tbx_Value3" runat="server" />
```

So, on post back the view state of tbx_Value1, tbx_Value2 and the GridView are retained, but the view state of tbx_ValueValue3 is lost. Setting `EnableViewState="true"` does not improve the situation.

The JQuery download is called in the following javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var c = 0;
    c = '<%=this.col %>';

    $(document).ready(function() {

        gridviewScroll(c);
    });

    function gridviewScroll(c) {

        $('#<%=gv_Data.ClientID%>').gridviewScroll({
            width: 1350,
            height: 330,
            freezesize: c,
            arrowsize: 30,
            varrowtopimg: "../../../images/arrowvt.png",
            varrowbottomimg: "../../../images/arrowvb.png",
            harrowleftimg: "../../../images/arrowhl.png",
            harrowrightimg: "../../../images/arrowhr.png",
            headerrowcount: 1
        });
    } 
</script>
```

I am at a loss as to how to address this. I have moved my controls around, recreated the page, rebuilt the application. All of this returns the same result. So, I can only assume it has something to do with the javascript (or jquery download I am using). Perhaps when it is applied in the page life cycle? Javascript/jquery is not my strong point, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: By _Java_ you mean _JavaScript_? Please be specific.

Comment: yes. It is the jquery I linked to and the javascript I have sited in the post.

Comment: Check if the jQuery moves the `input` fields outside the `</form>` tag. There was a [similar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41639331/gridview-rowcommand-not-firing) recently  where a modal popup placed a GridView outside of the form.

Comment: Thank you VDWWD. I will look at that.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not see anything which implies that the input fields have been moved.

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit to this query. The Gridview in this situation is dynamically created based on user input. I did not fathom anyone would request or need a very large GridView. However, when they did, the nature of this Gridview being what it is, resulted in a lot of controls being created.

Once I realized this was happening I updated the web.config appSettings key: "aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" to a larger number, but also restricted the size a user can request.

I arrived at this solution by way of this post:
['Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object' error during postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832470/operation-is-not-valid-due-to-the-current-state-of-the-object-error-during-pos)