# Click event not working from Dialog box in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have created a dialog box that open up from the aspx page. The dialog box contains information along with the buttons on the footer. MERGE and Close.

Below is the dialog box that I used for opening. This is successfully getting created and information a getting populated. However, when I am clicking on the "MERGE" button of the dialog box it does nothing as navigation is not transferred to the code behind file.

I have successfully defined the Click event on my code behind, but I don't understand why it is not firing it.

**aspx page**

```
<div class="modal-dialog" id="updateConfirmPopUp" style="display: none">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header" id="popUpHeader">
            <button type="button" class="close closePopup">
                <span>&times;</span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="confirmData">
            <div id="random"></div>
            <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <uc:ReviewGroupGrids ID="reviewGroupCtrls" runat="Server" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Review Next" OnClick="btnMerge_Click" />
            <button type="button" id="btnClosePopUp" class="btn btn-default closePopup">
                Okay</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**aspx.cs page**

```
protected void btnMerge_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // SessionUtility.SetSession(Constants.LASTREVIEWGROUPIDPROCESSED, this.ReviewGroup.ReviewGroupId);
            if (preventEvents)
            {
                Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl, false);
                return;
            }


            // ensure no action taken on current review group(partially or completly)
            #region Handle review group for completly processed case
            var selectedAssignment = SessionUtility.GetSession(Constants.SELECTEDUSERASSIGNMENT) as Assignment;
            var currentReviewGroupID = hdnReviewGroupID.Value.ToString();

            if (currentReviewGroupID != selectedAssignment.ReviewGroupId)
            {
                selectedAssignment.ReviewGroupId = currentReviewGroupID;
                SessionUtility.SetSession(Constants.SELECTEDUSERASSIGNMENT, selectedAssignment);
                LoadNextReviewGroup(null, null);
                lblPreviousReviewGroupId.Text = string.Format(StaticConstants.REVIEWGROUPVALIDATIONMESSAGE, currentReviewGroupID);
                lblPreviousReviewGroupId.Visible = true;
                return;
            }


            #endregion
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedIds))
            {
                SessionUtility.SetSession(Constants.USERSERLECTIONROWIDS, selectedIds);
                if (BtnMerge_Click != null)
                {
                    BtnMerge_Click(sender, e);
                }
                Response.Redirect("MergeGroup.aspx", false);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SessionUtility.SetSession(Constants.Error, ex);
            NavigationHelper.ToErrorPage(false);
        }
    }
```

My client click event is working fine.The only problem is with the onClick event.

Comment: have you using update panel at anywhere?

Comment: No I am not using update panel

Comment: I am not able to find the property "AutoPostBack"

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41639331/gridview-rowcommand-not-firing). The modal probably places the button outside the `</form>`.

Comment: @VDWWD: thank you for your answer. It worked. By the way is there any possibility of changing the link button. i.e. to make it appear like a button

Comment: Sure, use `css` to style it like a button.

Comment: Done. thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

An HTML Button can't call server side code. You have to use asp button with the runat="server" tag. something like

```
       <asp:Button ID="btnMerge" runat="server" Text="MERGE" OnClick="btnMerge_Click" />
```