# Edit template of the datagrid on jQuery dailog gets an error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Hi I have the datagrid in jquery dialog on the aspx page. When I clicked the 'Edit' link in the grid, it gets an error which is "JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property 'value' of undefined or null reference". I tested it to open the page in the new tab, not inside the jquery dialog, and it function run as expect.  Would someone tell me how I need to do.

My user control:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

the code behind of the user control:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim textbox As TextBox = Me.Parent.FindControl("txtCustomer")

    Dim url As String = "openDailog('popOrder.aspx?Id=" & textbox.Text & "', 'Order', 800, 200);"
    LinkButton1.Attributes.Add("onclick", url)

End Sub
```

My javascript:

```
function openDailog(url, name, width, height) {
 $('#dialog-box').dialog({
    my: "center",
    at: "center",
    of: window,
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: true,
    max_height: 'auto',
    height: 'auto',
    width: width,
    title: name,
    modal: true,
    draggable: true,
    open: function () {
        $(this).load(url);
    },
});


$('#dialog-box').dialog('open');
  return false;
}
```

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41707237/5836671

Comment: @VDWWD, it didn't work. I posted the code.