# Pressing enter in modal closes the modal but does not submit the data

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, webforms

I'm using asp.net webforms, and bootstrap 3
The problem I'm having is when pressing enter, having the password field focused dismisses the modal, but no data is submitted.

Seeing others had a similar problem but different elements in their modal, I for an example have asp:button in my code while others who could make it work had input type="submit" instead.

```
<div class="modal fade borderless" id="reviewSign" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></a>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">You are about to review document:
                            <asp:Label ID="lblReviewSignDocName" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblReviewSignDocNr" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <h5>Enter credentials and press "Ok" to review</h5>
                        <br />
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Username: </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserForReview" Class="form-control" Placeholder="Login Credentials" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Password: </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPasswordForReview" Class="form-control" Placeholder="Password" TextMode="Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <div runat="server" id="LNoteReviewSignDiv" visible="false">
                            <br />
                            <asp:Label ID="LNoteReviewSign" ForeColor="Red" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            <br />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Ok" ID="btnReviewSign" OnClick="btnReviewSign_Click" />
                        <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script type='text/javascript'>
                function openmodalReviewSign() {
                    $('[id=reviewSign]').modal('show');
                    $("#<%=txtPasswordForReview.ClientID %>").focus(200);
                }
            </script>
        </div>
```

What is expected is that pressing enter while the password field is focused would have the same effect as pressing the sign button. the other input field is set to readonly from the code behind so it can't be focused.

alternatively if submitting by pressing enter can't be achieved I would prefer nothing happening when pressing enter.

Comment: Use a LinkButton instead of a Button control. Then it will work. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41707237/5836671

Comment: Wrap inputs and buttons in `asp:Panel` and set `DefaultButton="btnReviewSign"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @AlexKudryashev suggested, wrapping all inputs and buttons in an asp:Panel and setting DefaultButton="btnReviewSign" solved this issue.

keep in mind this will only solve this problem if you're coding your website in .net webforms.